# Having issues with creating pivot table with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been able to somewhat create a pivot table and I will show you what I mean. Here is my code so far.

```
Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim FinalCol As Long
Dim StartPT As String
Set WSD = Worksheets("aggregateData")
Set WSD2 = Worksheets("Sheet12")


' Select the data for pivot table

FinalRow = WSD.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
FinalCol = WSD.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = WSD.Cells(2, 1).Resize(FinalRow, FinalCol)
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'Where do I want the pivot table to start

StartPT = WSD2.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)


'Begin to Create the Pivot Table

Set PT = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=StartPT, TableName:="POS Data")

PT.PivotFields("Fineline").Orientation = xlRowField


End Sub
```

When I run this code, I get the beginnings of a pivot table. However, the pivot table appears as white instead of the blue that a normal pivot table has. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace this row `Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)` of your code with this code `Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)` . xlPivotTableVersion15 is standard blue version of PivotTable. Please confirm if this resolves your question.

Comment: Hey, I get the error "Compile Error: Named Argument Not Found" I am using Excel 2010 if that means anything

Comment: Try xlPivotTableVersion14 if you are using Excel 2010.

Comment: It is highlighting "Version" and telling me that error

Comment: Did you replace ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add with ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create? I'm reproducing same macro on my 2010 Excel and it is working...